# .NET MAUI Binding to another element's property doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, maui

I have this code in my XAML:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="0">
    <Label x:Name="lblDistanceText"
       Text="Distance"
       FontSize="Medium"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Line Stroke="DarkGreen"
          StrokeThickness="3"
          StrokeLineCap="Round"
          Opacity="0.85"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          X2="{Binding Source={x:Reference lblDistanceText}, Path=Width}">
        <Line.Shadow>
            <Shadow Brush="DarkGreen"
                Offset="0,0"
                Radius="6"
                Opacity="0.9" />
        </Line.Shadow>
    </Line>
    <Label 
       Text="{Binding TotalDistance}"
       FontSize="Medium"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

It draws the green line that underlines the "Distance" text.

It works fine on Android but doesn't work on iOS.

Here is how it looks on iOS:

[image: iOS bug]

I've tested this on simulator and 2 real devices - same result.
Breakpoint isn't hit on the binding.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be replicated on my side. When setting `X2="{Binding Source={x:Reference lblDistanceText}, Path=Width}">` of the line, it failed to work in `iOS`,however, it functioned well in `Windows` and `Android`.

I would suggest that you can follow up:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14577 on Github.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.